# NgbTooltip position in Angular application

Tags: html, css, ng-bootstrap, angular

In my `Angular` 2/4 application, I use `ng-bootstrap` and its component `NgbTooltip`.

Assume the following `HTML` snippet

```
<div class="col-sm-8 text-ellipsis" 
     ngbTooltip="'A very long text that does not fit'" 
     placement="top" 
     container="body">
    A very long text that does not fit
</div>
```

with given custom `CSS`

```
.text-ellipsis {
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

**I am not happy with my implementation yet, maybe someone can help me find an elegant solution to my problem:**

Assume the text doesn't fit on the `div`, then it will be truncated and appended with "..." as expected and the tooltip shows on the top of the center of the `div`. This is good for this case, but when having very short content, it looks ugly:

```
<div class="col-sm-8 text-ellipsis" 
     ngbTooltip="'1.jpg'" 
     placement="top" 
     container="body">
    1.jpg
</div>
```

[image]

Now the tooltip still shows in the top center of the div, but way on the right of the text (because it is so short but the `div` still the full width).

I thought that I could easily solve this issue by using a `span` element and set the tooltip on that instead of the `div`:

```
<div class="col-sm-8 text-ellipsis">
    <span  
     ngbTooltip="'A very long text that does not fit'" 
     placement="top" 
     container="body">
        A very long text that does not fit
    </span>
</div>
```

But this workaround raises another issue as seen here:

[image]

The problem now is that the span gets truncated, but is in fact wider than the `div`. The tooltip renders in the middle of the `span` and not the `div`.

Any "smooth" idea how to make this nicer? I would appreciate your input a lot.

Comment: Did you get this the way you want it?

Comment: @Winnemucca actually not yet...

Comment: Have you tried to set `placement="top-left"` to the tooltip?

Answer (score 1):

This is a general answer, but check into your width versus min-width settings on the div. Also, span is an inline element and does not have block-level properties like width. You either need to use another div or you need to define the span as a display:inline-block in your CSS.

For the outer div, set a min-width where you'd like the ellipsis to start appearing (say at about 150px). Remove the text-ellipsis class from the div and put it on the span. For the span element, add a width of 100% and make it an inline-block (or just use another div)

So, basically, you end up with something like this (I put the min-width:150px inline, but of course this would be better in the style sheet):

```
<style>
    .text-ellipsis {
        white-space: nowrap;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>

<div class="col-sm-8" style="min-width: 150px">
    <div class="text-ellipsis" ngbTooltip="A very long text that does not fit" placement="top" container="body">
        A very long text that does not fit A very long text that does not fit A very long text that does not fitA very long text that does not fit A very long text that does not fit
    </div>
</div>
```